# How to Auto Login using VBS script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, tabs

I'm just new to this. I am currently working for a project here in our office and I already have the script on how to open multi-tab IE in one window. Here is the script that I use for it.

```
Const navOpenInBackgroundTab = &H1000

site1 = "http://site1.com/"
site2 = "https://site2.com"



Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate2 site1
oIE.Navigate2 site2,navOpenInBackgroundTab



Set oIE = Nothing
```

But two of these websites needs log in information. I want to know the script that will allow me to auto log in to these websites. I was wondering what I need to add on the script above so that it will auto-log in every time I use the script.

Here is one of the website:
https://myapps.uhc.com/Citrix/AccessPlatform/auth/login.aspx

I hope someone can help me figure it out, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you'd have an easier time using Firefox + Greasemonkey or Chrome + Tampermonkey.

Enumerating background tabs requires the use of `Shell.Application` object `.Windows()` method. The ambiguous window object seems to break `DOMelement.parentNode` and similar, so that each time you navigate the DOM you have to re-establish the complete hierarchy starting with `tabCollection.item(i).document`. Is the username field named user, username, login name, login ID, email, or something else?  You can try to predict it with a regex, but there'll probably be some trial and error involved if you plan to extend this script for logging into other sites.

The impossible part, though, is form submission. Does the form submission call a postback to set hidden input values prior to post? If so, then `form.submit()` might not fire the necessary events before submission, resulting in an auth failure. This was the case for two sites I tested.

If you could fire the `click()` event of the submit button, that might help. But is the submit button a button? An input type=button? An image? A stylized hyperlink? A div? OK, so maybe sending <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the password field would be better. I've been experimenting with `initKeyboardEvent` and `passwordField.dispatchEvent(evt)` for a couple of hours now, and it seems that here again, the ambiguous `window` object resulting from `Shell.Application` is preventing success.

Here's my *almost*-working solution.  It's a batch + Jscript hybrid.  Save it with a .bat extension, and do with it what you will.  *shrug*  Maybe `form.submit()` will work for the sites you are using?

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"
goto :EOf

@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid code

var navOpenInBackgroundTab = 4096,
    site = [
        "http://www.site1.com/",
        "http://www.site2.com/"
    ],
    IE = WSH.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application"),
    oSH = WSH.CreateObject("Shell.Application"),
    username = 'username',
    password = 'password';

IE.Visible = true;

for (var i=0; i<site.length; i++) {
    IE.Navigate(site[i], i ? 4096 : null);
}

var tabs = oSH.Windows();

for (var x = 0; x < tabs.Count; x++) {
    if (!!(tabs.item(x))) {
        WSH.Echo('tab ' + x);
        var entered = { 'username': 0, 'password': 0 };
        while (tabs.item(x).Busy || tabs.item(x).ReadyState != 4) WSH.Sleep(50);
        // sleep 1 second regardless, just in case there's some jquery crap going on
        WSH.Sleep(1000);
        for (var i in tabs.item(x).document.forms) {
            if (i == 'length') break;
            var inputs = tabs.item(x).document.forms[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var j = inputs.length; j--;) {
                if (/\b(login|user(name|id)?|e\-?mail)\b/i.test(inputs[j].name)
                && inputs[j].type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                    entered.username = inputs[j];
                    inputs[j].value = username;
                } else if (inputs[j].type.toLowerCase() == 'password') {
                    entered.password = inputs[j];
                    inputs[j].value = password;
                }
            }
            if (entered.username && entered.password) {
                tabs.item(x).document.forms[i].submit();

                /* === NOT QUITE WORKING ===
                try {
                    var evt = tabs.item(x).document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
                    // What is "window"? tabs.item(x) doesn't work, nor does IE.
                    evt.initKeyboardEvent('keypress', true, true, tabs.item(x),
                        false, false, false, false, 13, 13);
                    entered.password.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }
                catch(e) { WSH.Echo(e.message) }
                */

                i = tabs.item(x).document.forms.length;
            }
        }
    }
}

var IE = null;
```

Another idea would be to do `passwordElement.focus()` and use `WshShell.SendKeys()` to send Enter, but then you wouldn't be able to load the tabs in the background.  I haven't found a way to activate tabs programmatically yet;  but if they're loaded in the foreground, they're already active.  Although this doesn't load tabs in the background, it works better than the first method.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"
goto :EOf

@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid code

var sites = {
        "http://www.site1.com/" : {
            'username': 'site1user',
            'password': 'site1pass'
        },
        "http://www.site2.net/" : {
            'username': 'site2user',
            'password': 'site2pass'
        }
    },
    IE = WSH.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application"),
    oSH = WSH.CreateObject("Shell.Application"),
    WshShell = WSH.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"),
    proc = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("SELECT Handle FROM Win32_Process "
        + "WHERE Name='iexplore.exe'"),
    handle = new Enumerator(proc).item().Handle;

awesomeness:
for (var url in sites) {

    // if not a new window, open a new tab
    IE.Navigate(url, IE.Visible ? 2048 : null);
    IE.Visible = true;

    // give the tab a chance to load
    WSH.Sleep(1000);

    var tabs = oSH.Windows(),
        tab = tabs.item(tabs.Count - 1),
        entered = { 'username': 0, 'password': 0 };

    while (tab.Busy || tab.ReadyState != 4) WSH.Sleep(50);

    for (var i in tab.document.forms) {
        if (i == 'length') break;
        var inputs = tab.document.forms[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var j = inputs.length; j--;) {
            if (/\b(login|user(name|id)?|e\-?mail)\b/i.test(inputs[j].name)
            && inputs[j].type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                entered.username = inputs[j].value = sites[url].username;
            } else if (inputs[j].type.toLowerCase() == 'password') {
                entered.password = inputs[j];
                inputs[j].value = sites[url].password;
            }
            if (entered.username && entered.password) {
                // force IE window to have focus
                while (!(WshShell.AppActivate(handle))) WSH.Sleep(50);
                entered.password.focus();
                WshShell.SendKeys('{END}{ENTER}');
                continue awesomeness;
            }
        }
    }
}

var IE = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try this out using batch file. I may have to do some trial and error. I'll let you know if this works. ☺

Comment: @kiantaray See my second solution.  It works better than the first, if you can live with the tabs not loading as background tabs and the focus ending on the final tab rather than the first.

Comment: Hi, I've found an easier argument for me to automatically load username and password. But I'm still trying to figure out how to open it in multi-tab with at least 2 or 3 sites automatically logged in. Here is what I have:

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
call WshShell.Run("website", 1, false) 'This will open your default browser



WScript.Sleep 6000
WshShell.SendKeys "username"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "password"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit()

Comment: Hi, I've found an easier argument for me to automatically load username and password. But I'm still trying to figure out how to open it in multi-tab with at least 2 or 3 sites automatically logged in. Here is what I have:

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
call WshShell.Run("website", 1, false) 'This will open your default browser

WScript.Sleep 6000
WshShell.SendKeys "username"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "password"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit()