# Inject javascript code to Google Chrome while opening a page through Command Line / Batch File

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, batch-file

I have this command running though a batch file

```
chrome.exe --app=https://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

I would like to run a script (e.g. to increase font size) after opening the page through the batch file

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can script Internet Explorer with Windows Script Host ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35594057/1683264)), but not other browsers.  You'd either need to [`SendKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to send keystrokes to manipulate Chrome after launching it (for example:

```
powershell "$sh = new-object -COM Wscript.Shell; $sh.AppActivate('Chrome'); $sh.sendkeys(\"^^{+}\")"
```

... to increase the font size), or use [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) to load a user script from the browser side.

Comment: @Insane96MCP I suggest loading a user script or two ([this one would be a great one](http://stackapps.com/q/5038/29449) for example, if I don't say so myself) and examining them to figure out how they work.  TamperMonkey is basically a Google Chrome implementation of Firefox's Greasemonkey add-on.  The [Greasemonkey wiki](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page) would be a good place to learn about the structure of user scripts.